# Complex sort dictionary into sorted list

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have the following class:

```
class SalesRecord:
    name = ''
    dollarsSpent = 0
    itemsPurchased = 0
    itemsSold = 0
    position = 0
```

I also have a dictionary that is structured with a bunch of these SalesRecords with the SalesRecord.name as the key. How can I sort the values into a sorted list with the following criteria (Assume everything is an integer):

1. Sort by dollarsSpent desc
2. Then by itemsPurchased - itemsSold desc
3. Then by itemsPurchased desc
4. Then by position asc

Also, just curious, but what would the overall run-time of such a sort be? Does it need to iterate 4 times in the worst case?

Comment: Can you show the structure of your dictionary?

Comment: It is just a simple dictionary structure. Ex: 


`sales['Johnson1'] = the SalesRecord object where SalesRecord.name = 'Johnson1'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a compound key.

```
sorted((k, v) for (k, v) in somedict, key=lambda (k, v):
  (-v.dollarsSpent, -(v.itemsPurchased - v.itemsSold),
  -v.itemsPurchased, v.position))
```

Comment: What is the benefit of doing it this way versus option 1 as presented by user2357112?

Comment: It doesn't add another name to the scope. Which isn't that big a deal either way.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. Both options run in linearithmic time, `O(nlog(n))`, but you may consider one more readable. You can use a compound sort key:

```
def sortkey(salesrecord):
    r = salesrecord
    return (
        -r.dollarsSpent,
        -r.itemsPurchased + r.itemsSold,
        -r.itemsPurchased,
        r.position
    )
sorted(salesdict.values(), key=sortkey)
```

or sort multiple times, relying on the stability of the sort algorithm:

```
l = salesdict.values()
l.sort(key=lambda r: r.position)
l.sort(key=lambda r: r.itemsPurchased, reverse=True)
l.sort(key=lambda r: r.itemsPurchased - r.itemsSold, reverse=True)
l.sort(key=lambda r: r.dollarsSpent, reverse=True)
```

With a [stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability), you can sort by a number of keys with different priorities by sorting by each key from lowest priority to highest. After sorting by a higher-priority key, items that compare equal by that key are guaranteed to remain in the order they had after the lower-priority key sorts.

Comment: Would both options still sort in timsorts worst case time of O(nlog(n))?

Comment: @Gyrien: Yes. One might have a worse constant factor, but it probably won't matter.

Comment: Thanks! Also, why do you sort by r.position first in the second case?

Comment: @Gyrien: After sorting by `itemsPurchased`, any records with the same number of purchased items will be in the order they were in after the sort by `position`, so the list will be ordered by purchased items, then position. This principle applies to the next two sorts, too.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is to take advantage of [sort stability](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts) to sort in multiple stages (first by position, then by items purchased descending, etc).

This is less expensive than it seems because the [TimSort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) takes advantage the elements that are already partially ordered.

This approach is also easier to get right than trying to build an overly complex [key-function](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-key-function).